# Session hangs on session_start() in PHP

Tags: php, memcached

I've an issue where session_start() hangs.

I've tried replacing the "file" method with "memcached". This did not correct the problem.

The problem is not concurrent access. It's not that I'm trying to access an session with two separate scripts at the same time.

I can create the session and save it, but cannot access the session afterwards.

Checking in my session.save_path, I can see that the session file was created, and I don't see any problem with it.
Here is an example session file:

> sess_88senr7p8icjaiebup8i449l41:csrf|s:32:"401a0f9028b00102c671459da8537286";userdata|a:6:{s:2:"id";s:4:"3198";s:5:"email";s:25:"paul@***************.com";s:4:"name";s:17:"****************";s:6:"parent";s:4:"3198";s:11:"permissions";i:1;s:15:"app_permissions";N;}employer|a:8:{s:2:"id";s:4:"3198";s:12:"company_name";s:7:"******";s:21:"user_accounts_allowed";i:20;s:18:"user_accounts_used";i:20;s:5:"notes";s:0:"";s:14:"contract_start";s:10:"2013-04-10";s:12:"contract_end";s:10:"2014-04-10";s:8:"features";i:2;}

This is acting as if the session lock is simply not removed at all. Where would I check to find this? Would this same issue affect "file" and "memcached"?

Comment: Define "cannot access the session". A policeman steps on your way or what?

Comment: if I load another script after the first one has finished, the second script hangs at the session_start() line. it doesn't let me "access" the session.

Comment: Yes. if I "echo 1;exit;" before session_start(), then the script outputs 1 and then exits. If I "echo 2;exit;" /after/ session_start(), then the script doesn't reach that line. It hangs.